# Parse sql date column using groovy

Tags: sql, groovy

I am trying to parse SQL date using groovy.
Code :

```groovy
def res = con.firstRow("select fkItemID,DateTimeFrom,DateTimeTo,OriginalUTCStartDateTime,OriginalUTCEndDateTime from tblBookingItem where fkBookingID='$bookingId' and active=1" )
def sqlDateTimeFrom = res.DateTimeFrom.toString()
log.info "time : " + sqlDateTimeFrom
sql_sdate =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse(sqlDateTimeFrom)
```

Error popup :

```
Unparseable date: "2020-01-15 10:00:00.0"
```

Output :

```
Wed Jan 15 15:25:36 IST 2020:INFO:time : 2020-01-15 10:00:00.0
```

Comment: res.DateTimeFrom - is already a date. you don't need to parse it. maybe you want to format it to string?

Comment: yes right. I need to format it to the desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.DateTimeFrom` - is already a date. you don't need to parse it.

if you want to format it:

```groovy
def res = con.firstRow("select fkItemID,DateTimeFrom,DateTimeTo,OriginalUTCStartDateTime,OriginalUTCEndDateTime from tblBookingItem where fkBookingID='$bookingId' and active=1" )
def strDateTimeFrom = res.DateTimeFrom.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
log.info "time : " + strDateTimeFrom
```